# Need help connecting my advertisement table to my advertisement images table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need the ad_id from my ad-table (which contains values such as ad_title, ad_description, ad_price, etc...) and I need to insert it into the ad-images table(that contains values such as the ad_name, ad_image_name and ad_id) as a foreign key.

My issue is that when I insert the ad image values, I need the ad_id from the ad-table. But I am inserting values into the ad-table at the same time as I am inserting values into the ad-image table. How do I get the ad_id from the ad-table to make a foreign key with the ad-image table

As you can see in the code here: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $ad_id, $fileNameNew);`

I need to get the ad_id but I don't know where to get that value from since I am executing the sql statement at the same time as I add information into the ad-table

Comment: Can you post your database structure?

Comment: added structure of database

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`